# How to restore the new 14.04-lockscreen

Tags: unity, compiz, lock-screen, 14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 but since some weeks I'm stuck with the old 13.10 lockscreen design for some reason. 
I already tried compizconfig-settings-manager but it doesn't offer me any option for changing the lockscreen design and even resetting Compiz and Unity with

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

didn't help.

Are there any other ways to get the new lockscreen back?

Comment: I am having same kind of issue In cmd lsb_release -a shows Ubuntu 14.04
But on lightdm login it shows 13.10 Also I am not able to login it freezes when I
I enter the password

Comment: I suggest deleting `.`-files relating to the session (but not all of them, e.g. `.mozilla`, `.thunderbird` and so on!)

Comment: I tried deleting everything related to compiz or unity but it didn't help. In the end I just created a new user, copied my stuff over to it and deleted to old one. Now I have the fancy lockscreen back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue because of the on-screen keyboard. After I disabled it, the fancy lockscreen got re-enabled

Comment: Just tested disabling Onboard after I got the old lockscreen and it worked. The problem is that I have installed Ubuntu on a tablet where Onboard is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Filled in a bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1310404

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 - disabling on board keyboard fixes it also. I've been suffering from this few weeks until figured this out! Thanks