# Unity lock screen issue

Tags: lock-screen

I upgraded from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 and I still have the old lock screen. How do I change to the new one?

There was a compiz option to change between the two of them but it was removed in the last update :(

I use 64 bit version of Trusty.

Answer (score 1):

A very similar question was [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449623/howto-restore-the-new-14-04-lockscreen) was asked. Apparently Onboard (the onscreen keyboard) can cause this to happen.

Fix: [Disable Onboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84050/how-do-i-disable-the-on-screen-keyboard-in-the-unlock-screen)