# I see gnome-screensaver lock screen instead of unity one. What happened and how to fix it?

Tags: 14.04, lts, unity-greeter, gnome-screensaver

For a long time in 14.04.1 LTS I see gnome-screensaver lock screen instead of unity-greeter (or which one is the latest and greatest?). I've already tried to `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and `dpkr-reconfigure unity-greeter`. It doesn't help. And there's no lockscreen selection dropdown in CCSM's Unity plugin preferences (but I've faced screenshots with it on `webupd8`). Simple uninstalling of `gnome-screensaver` also didn't work. How can I enable/revert back unity lock screen? 
Thanks.

p.s. `dm-tool switch-to-greeter` or `dm-tool lock` also work both and after successful screen unlock I see `gnome-screensaver` unlock screen, so I'm unlocking screen twice.

Comment: Thanks man, precisely the problem. After many searches, the answer is that simple (feeling dumb). I've reconfigured and re-installed following every forum post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that [screen reader](https://askubuntu.com/a/562296/1846) (like in  my case) and [on-screen keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/a/451451/1846) can cause this. Had to disable all tools in `System settings/Universal access`.