# First login screen is gnome, screensaver is lightdm

Tags: gnome, login, lightdm, screensaver

I know I tried a bunch of fixes last week but nothing seemed to work.

I have gnome-screensaver installed and the first time I log in(after power off or restart) it shows up.

Then if I leave my laptop on idle or lock it manually, this monstrosity shows up:

[image: monstrosity]

Of course this picture is from Google but its exactly how mine looks.

I dont remember changing anything from the installation except installing gnome and I remember actually deleting lightdm which did nothing aswell.

Any ideas? How do I make my lockscreen great again?

EDIT:

dpkg-l output:

[image: output1]

GDM3 is definitely installed.

[image]

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/152256/how-do-i-switch-from-lightdm-to-gdm  But look at the last part of the accepted answer.  There is a possibility that something reinstalled lightdm.

Comment: Nope. Tried doing this. I cant stop lightdm it never offers me to choose the monitor.

Comment: So, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` doesn't bring up anything?

Comment: @Terrance https://i.imgur.com/CKZRp8Q.png nope. It's actually amazing LOL

Comment: WOW!  That is interesting.  Which screensaver are you using?

Comment: Gdm3 is the thing thats supposed to be running @Terrance

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` should bring up the selection then.  I was asking about gnomescreensaver or XScreensaver, etc.

Comment: @Terrance it doesnt https://i.imgur.com/jj47b1i.png and when I try on a big terminal, nothing happens, the command goes through but no prompts

Comment: One last thing.  Edit your question and add the output of `dpkg -l *screensaver`

Comment: The solution that worked for me is, https://askubuntu.com/a/566517