# Why did my lock screen change?

Tags: 14.10, lock-screen

My lock screen changed one day from the default:
[image: lock screen before]

to this different one:
[image: lock screen after]

I am running Ubuntu 14.10. The install was originally a 14.04 that I upgraded to 14.10.  The lock screen did not change at that point.  Since then, I've just simply been periodically installing updates and adding software packages here and there.  I'm not positive but I think the lock screen changed after I installed some packages from the Ubuntu repos (might have been [MuseScore](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/musescore/)) using apt-get.

This is not a big deal, but I wish I knew *why* it randomly changed . Any idea why it did this?

Edit:  [Here is the output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9287902/) of `dpkg --get-selections | -v deinstall`, as requested by Tim.

Comment: you might have installed some other desktop

Comment: As far as I know, Unity is all that is installed.  Is there a good way to find out if there are other desktop environments installed?

Comment: Please edit your question to include more information regarding what you did between the time you had the default login screen and the new one. Random changes are unlikely and when they occur they are normally the result of A) Operator error or B) Hardware failing.

Comment: Did you install unity tweak tool!?

Comment: @Tim Unity Tweak Tool is installed, but it has been installed since my original Ubuntu 14.04 install back in June or so. The new lock screen first appeared for me only about 2-3 weeks ago.

Comment: Try removing it. That's what the problem was for me. Something else may have triggered it, but I think that UTT is the problem

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get remove unity-tweak-tool` then restarted the laptop, but it did not change the lock screen.  I also did a `apt-get autoremove` and that did not make a difference either.

Comment: Have you tried removing whatever it was you thought triggered it?

Comment: Yes, I've run `sudo apt-get remove musescore` and that did not change the lock screen either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem. For some reasons, my "Screen Reader" option in "Universal Access" was turned on (I suspect my daughter) and was preventing the new lock screen to kick in.

Apparently, "on-screen keyboard" option could also cause this behaviour as suggested in this thread:

[How to restore the new 14.04-lockscreen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449623/howto-restore-the-new-14-04-lockscreen)

I suggest you check in System Settings > Universal Access to see if you have any option enabled that could be the cause of the problem.

Good luck

Comment: Bingo. Indeed, my "Screen Reader" was turned on.  I'm wondering if that got toggled on when I accidentally ran the Orca screen reader about the time the lock screen changed on me.  I turned the Screen Reader off, and the Lock Screen is back to the default one.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue for me, too. It turns out that if you accidentally press the key combination Alt+Super+S, the screen reader is activated. I suspect this is what I did to cause the setting to change.

Comment: On screen keyboard was activated and disabling it fixed this issue for me, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Both the lock screen exist in your system. The first one is provided by **Lightdm**, you can try

```
dm-tool lock
```

The second one is provided by **gnome**, use

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

To set `dm-tool` as your desired lock screen install, `compizconfig-settings-manager`

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Go to **CompizConfig Settings Manager**, click on **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** and on the **General** tab, under **Lockscreen**, you can select LightDM lockscreen.

[image]

[webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-switch-between-new-unity.html) described how to switch between unity and lightdm lock screen.

Comment: He want's the default to be the gnome one. How can that be done?

Comment: @souravc, using `dm-tool lock` did indeed lock to the Unity lock screen!  However, when I unlocked from that screen, it unlocked to the Gnome lock screen...at which point I need to enter my password to unlock a second time... To my knowledge I don't think I ever installed Gnome. I wonder why I am getting Gnome's lock screen?

Comment: @dazzle it is very difficult to find out the reason, have you recently installed/modified anything?

Comment: @souravc, the "webupd8" link in your post just goes to imgur. I installed the CompizConfig Settings Manager like you recommended-- the "General" tab looks axactly like the screen shot you posted, except without the lock screen option... See [this screencap](http://i.imgur.com/TlDNCSN.png)

Comment: @dazzle I have updated the link, see now

Comment: Can you run this command `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | pastebinit` and post the link it gives you. We may be able to see if there is something strage there.

Comment: @souravc, I'd love to 'accept' your answer but unfortunately my version of CCSM (v0.9.12) does not give me the Lockscreen options.  I upvoted your answer because it has been helpful in diagnosing the problem, and I hope it helps people in the future that come across this post, but for me it did not work.

Comment: sorry it did not worked for you. I will try to find something that can help you.

Comment: @dazzle same here, the lock option does not appear. In my case I never had lightdm lockscreen except on new account

Answer (score 0):

i also have the same problem. read about it on other pages too but couldn't find a solution. neither by terminal commands.
finally i find a solution. i turned off the on screen keyboard from the Universal access -> Typing menu and i got my old dm-tool lock screen.
This worked for me.